# Smart association of graphs where one is faceted - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I want to combine these two graphs :

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Species)

p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_density()
```

To combine, I do :

```
multiplot(p1, p2, cols = 2)
```

But it is not the desired shape.

I would like the graph p2 has the same dimensions than others and is situated just next to the last faceted graph.

Thanks for help

Comment: `facet_grid(~ Species, margins = TRUE)` will work here. But for the general case, this is not easy to do. The `cowplot` package does alignments, but you can't align facetted and non-facetted plots.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable in you generic case, but with `facet_grid` instead of `facet_wrap`, you can use the `margins` argument:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + 
    geom_density() + 
    facet_grid(. ~ Species, margins = T)
```

[image]

If you question is more generic the answer probably lies in `grid.arrange`.
Something like this could be a start:

```
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1, p2, 
                         widths = c(3,1), 
                         heights = c(1,20), 
                         layout_matrix = matrix(c(1,1,NA,2),2)))
```

[image]

As you can see there are several problems (different axes, top strip), but working with `grid` could gets complicated quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + 
      geom_density() + 
      ylim(limits = c(0, 1.25))+
      facet_wrap(~ Species)

p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + 
      geom_density() +
      ggtitle("") + # ad empty title as place holder
      labs(y = "", x = "") + # hide axis labels
      ylim(limits = c(0, 1.25)) + # y axis values should be fixed in both plots
      coord_fixed(ratio=20/1) + # ratio of x- and y-axis to reduce width of plot
      theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.line.y = element_blank(),
      plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0.65,-10), "lines")) # margin between plots = "0.65"
```

I fiddled a bit and used just different styling options to produce this result. If you have more plots than this one I would recommend to use one theme for all.

You can use either the multiplot function that you are already using

```
multiplot(p1, p2, cols = 2)
```

or you install the packages gridExtra and grid and use that one:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

Hope this helps!